# html fonts look jagged... photoshop vs html/css version

Tags: css, fonts, size

Is it normal that fonts I used to create site layout are pixelated? I use Georgia, and in photoshop I've smooth lines everything looks great. But when I tried to slice it up and code the css, Georgia font same size looks noticeably uglier!

What are your thoughts?

p.s. I use em to declare sizes in css.

Comment: Yes, it's normal for fonts to look completely different in Photoshop vs in browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fonts on the web will look a little pixellated unless you're on a Mac which renders type considerably better than PC.

The best way I have found to replicate how a font will look on the web is to set the Anitialiasing in Photoshop to 'sharp'.

It is conceivable that there will be CSS markup in the future that will allow antialiasing in the browser rather than OS based.

**It is a common problem.**

See this article
http://jontangerine.com/log/2007/10/smoothing-out-the-creases-in-web-fonts

The alternative is to use something like Cufon that generates images for your text. Best practice would be to only use it for headings.
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Answer (score 2):

That's because photoshop is using anti-alias technique on text.

Both OS and browser will impact the appearance of text in web page.For example, Mac OS has anti-alias text on all system UI. For windows, I believe they have an option called 'ClearType', once switched on all system UI will have smooth texts.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this too - each browser renders fonts differently. I often find fonts look much better in IE. Sometimes I opt to use images created in PS to get that smooth look, but for the most part I think people are used to how fonts are rendered in their browser of choice.

Answer (score 0):

In photoshop, there's an option to "smooth" text.

[See this image](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/spiderman/chardialog.png). Bottom right corner.

Remove this anti-alising to have a better view (but not exact) of how the font will look in browser.